# Plotting great circles from a subset in R

Tags: r, maps, subset, great-circle

I have a data frame that after some processing (as geocoding for example) has the following characteristics:

```
'data.frame':   13 obs. of  5 variables:
$ id      : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...  
$ ciudad  : Factor w/ 10 levels "Auch","Barcelona",..: 8 4 5 3 2 7 9 10 6 6 ...  
$ proyecto: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...  
$ lon     : num  -1.131 0.564 -9.139 0.627 2.173 ...  
$ lat     : num  38 44.2 38.7 44.5 41.4 ...
```

Every proyect (proyecto) has a list of cities. **And I need to connect in a radial-way the first of them with the others (of the project)**. That is what I have been done so far:

```
# Capitalizing first letters
municipios <- read.csv("ciudades.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";")
stri_trans_totitle(as.character(municipios$ciudad))
write.csv(municipios, file = "municipios.csv")

# Obtaining latitude & longitude
lonlat <- geocode(as.character(municipios$ciudad))
municipios_lonlat <- cbind(municipios, lonlat)
write.csv(municipios_lonlat, file = "municipios_lonlat.csv")

str(municipios_lonlat)

# Plotting a simple map
xlim <- c(-13.08, 8.68)
ylim <- c(34.87, 49.50)
map("world", col="#191919", fill=TRUE, bg="#000000", lwd=0.05, xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim)

# Plotting cities
symbols(municipios_lonlat$lon, municipios_lonlat$lat, bg="#e2373f", fg="#ffffff", lwd=0.5, circles=rep(1, length(municipios_lonlat$lon)), inches=0.05, add=TRUE)

# Subsetting, splitting & connecting
uniq <- unique(unlist(municipios_lonlat$proyecto))
for (i in 1:length(uniq)){
  data_1 <- subset(municipios_lonlat, proyecto == uniq[i])
  for (i in 2:length(data_1$lon)-1){
    lngs <- c(data_1$lon[1], data_1$lon[i])
    lats <- c(data_1$lat[1], data_1$lat[i])
    lines(lngs, lats, col="#e2373f", lwd=2)
  }
}
```

But it does not like quite real. **So I need to use great circles to improve the resulting map.** I know I have to use the geosphere library, and use a similar loop as the one I have done in the last paragraph. But the things I tried did not work. Please could you help me. You are my only hope Obi Wan Kenobis.

Note: [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2wHnLxPlbTHRGpCbVJxVVdheG8/view?usp=sharing) you can download my data.

Comment: [This post](http://flowingdata.com/2011/05/11/how-to-map-connections-with-great-circles/) does a very good job of describing a technique.

Comment: If you would provide data, some will be able to help you. Please consider using `dput`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @jazzurro I have already done that. Hopefully someone can help me. Thanks again.